# Is it possible to run a batch file in user's profile at once after logging into it automatically having done some settings in Active Directory?

Tags: batch-file, automation, active-directory

I have a batch file containing a script that automates an operation. I would like that the batch file can be run at loading into user's Windows machine profile of a local network. Can I get this action done using the Active Directory for all selected users such that as a user get logged into his/her own profile the batch file executes for the one immediately? Can it get done if the batch file can be only run from an administator credentials?

Answer (score 2):

Active Directory allows logon scripts to be run pretty easily.

Step 1: Place the script in:
`\\MyDomainController\SYSVOL\myFQDN\scripts` Create scripts folder if it isn't there. All domain controllers have this shared volume that the GPOs get shared out all domain computers. Just type `\\DC` into file explorer and it will take to the root of the share where you can drill down, replacing DC with the hostname of your domain controller.

For this example, I will name the script `login1.bat`.

Step 2: Open `Active Directory Users and Groups` on the DC. Right click on the user you want to run the login script as and choose `Properties`. Click the `Logon` tab and in the box for `Logon Script`, type `login1.bat`.

That's it. Now that script will run when the user logs in on any machine.